# Perl While Loop/print only specific data/ uninitialized value

Tags: perl

Hey guys so my homework is to `"Print all records that do not list a discoverer in the eighth field."`

We are given a file that contains this information: This is how some of my information looks like:

```
Umbriel II Uranus 266000 4.14 0.00 0.00 Lassell 1851
Uranus VII Sun 2870990000 30685.00 0.77 0.05 Herschel 1781
Venus II Sun 108200000 224.70 3.39 0.01 - -
```

So this is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; 
use strict;

while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
     my @field = split(/\s+/, $line);
     my $discover = $field[7];
     if ($discover eq '- -') {
         print "\$discover\n";
     }
}
```

and I am receiving this error:

```
Use of uninitialized value $discover in string eq at ./ss123 line 7, <STDIN> line 2.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: You have a typo on your 12 line. It should read `my $discover = $field[8];` (There is still another mistake in this line).That said the program will not work with that fix. You should read some more about programming. Looks for instance here for arrays: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_arrays.htm . Also think about what `$nfield` will be when you do the assigment. Why do you do that? What is the `if` statement for, and why does it not work?

Comment: I have changed it to: while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
        my @field = split(/\s+/, $line);
        my $field = @field;
        my $discover = $field[8];
        if ($discover == "- -");
        print "\$discover\n";
I am using the `if` statement because if the eighth field doesn't have anything then those are to be printed. @bolav

Comment: Please, create a [mcve]. Describing your test data is not enough; we need to actually see it if you expect to receive a quality answer. Also, the eighth field would be array index 7, since Perl arrays are 0-indexed. And, this would be a good time to learn about string vs. numeric [comparison operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Comment: What do you think `my $field = @field;` does? (Hint: it doesn't do anything useful in your program.) Are you using the right comparison operator? (Hint: go read about the difference between `==` and `eq`.) Have you read the syntax rules for a Perl `if` modifier or `if` statement? (Hint: you should; what you have isn't either one and is causing the syntax error.)

Comment: You can remove everything between 'use strict' and your while loop.  Your'e redeclaring those variables anyway, and the <STDIN> line.  Also, you're likely hitting these error because you have lines that don't have at least 8 fields.

Comment: Why are you reading records from `STDIN`? Wouldn't the data be in a file? (so you wouldn't have to type them in on the terminal each time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is trivial if you search for the non-value correctly. Since you're splitting on whitespace, you'll never have `- -` as a single element of your resulting array. In the code below, I've increased the Data::Dumper indentation level to 3, which shows array indexes next to each element (helpful for debugging).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

$Data::Dumper::Indent = 3;

while (<DATA>) {
    my @fields = split;

    if ($fields[7] eq '-') {
        print Dumper(\@fields);
    }
}

__DATA__
Umbriel II Uranus 266000 4.14 0.00 0.00 Lassell 1851
Uranus VII Sun 2870990000 30685.00 0.77 0.05 Herschel 1781
Venus II Sun 108200000 224.70 3.39 0.01 - -
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          #0
          'Venus',
          #1
          'II',
          #2
          'Sun',
          #3
          '108200000',
          #4
          '224.70',
          #5
          '3.39',
          #6
          '0.01',
          #7
          '-',
          #8
          '-'
        ];
```